# Why is LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN or 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941 giving blank results for AD user's recursive groups?

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap3

Tried with below ldap queries.

```
ldap_query = "(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=user)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=xx,CN=Users,DC=aa,DC=ss,DC=com))"
ldap_query = "(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=xx,CN=Users,DC=aa,DC=ss,DC=com)"
```

Code is as below.

```
for hostname in <<domain.domain_controllers>>:
    tls = ldap3.Tls(validate=ssl.CERT_NONE, version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
    server = ldap3.Server(hostname, get_info=ldap3.ALL, mode=ldap3.IP_V4_PREFERRED, tls=tls, use_ssl=True)
    with ldap3.Connection(server=server, authentication=ldap3.NTLM, auto_bind=True, password=xx, read_only=True, receive_timeout=30,user=yy) as ldap_connection:
        search_parameters = {'search_base': 'DC=aa,DC=ss,DC=com', 'search_filter': ldap_query, 'attributes': ['*']}
        ldap_connection.search(**search_parameters)
        print(ldap_connection.entries)
```

It is just printing [] for all DCs, but user has groups and sub groups, as checked manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that `CN=xx,CN=Users,DC=aa,DC=ss,DC=com` is a user object, and you are trying to find groups that have that user as a member. Am I correct?

The first query won't work, since it is searching for *users* that have the `member` attribute set. Users don't have a `member` attribute.

The second query would return any object that has `CN=xx` as a member. The only objects that have a `member` attribute are groups, but you could further constrain it to only groups anyway, which might improve the performance of the query (since `objectClass` is indexed):

```
ldap_query = "(&(objectClass=group)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=xx,CN=Users,DC=aa,DC=ss,DC=com))"
```

There is no need to make the same query on every DC. They'll all give you the same information. If you aren't getting any results for this query, then there could be a few reasons:

1. There's something wrong with your connection details. Try making some other query you know should work like `(objectClass=user)` (which would return all user objects) and see if you get results.
2. The `distinguishedName` you're using is incorrect. Verify that it is correct. You can try searching for it like this: `(distinguishedName=CN=xx,CN=Users,DC=aa,DC=ss,DC=com)` and see if you get results.
3. If your AD forest has more than one domain, it's possible that the groups you are seeing are on another domain. Unless you are querying a Global Catalog (GC), you won't find groups on other domains.

Comment: Thanks. Based on the understanding gained from above I did this. 1.         ldap_query_find_all_groups = "(objectClass=group)" 2. ldap_query_find_our_user = "(&(objectClass=user)(distinguishedName=CN=surname\, name,OU=xx,OU=uu,OU=yy,OU=zz,OU=pp,OU=qq,OU=dd,DC=aa,DC=ss,DC=com))" 3. ldap_query_find_all_groups_with_our_user_as_member = "(&(objectClass=group)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=surname\, name,OU=xx,OU=uu,OU=yy,OU=zz,OU=pp,OU=qq,OU=dd,DC=aa,DC=ss,DC=com))". While first 2 queries are working, third one is getting timed out via python code. I will probably get help on that separately.

Comment: ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPSocketReceiveError: error receiving data: The read operation timed out - to be precise.